# Binomial probabilities, dividing by probabilities

Tags: probability, binomial-distribution, conditional-probability

First, my apologies if this is redundant or out of place. I Googled and searched but found nothing related.

I am trying to understand the logic of this equation:

$\frac{{p\left( {{\rm{at.least.one.c}}} \right) - p\left( {{\rm{exactly.one.c}}} \right)}}{{p\left( {{\rm{at.least.one.c}}} \right)}} = p\left( {{\rm{more.than.one.c|at.least.one.c}}} \right)
$

it comes from this binomial equation:

$\frac{{\left[ {1 - {{\left( {1 - \Pr } \right)}^N}} \right] - \left[ {N \cdot \Pr {{\left( {1 - \Pr } \right)}^{\left( {N - 1} \right)}}} \right]}}{{\left[ {1 - {{\left( {1 - \Pr } \right)}^N}} \right]}} = p\left( {1 + |1} \right)
$

where "c" is just a "match" so p(at.least.one.c) means the probability of getting at least one match. I hope the rest of the equation makes sense.

This comes from [People v. Collins (1968)](https://www.courtlistener.com/opinion/1207456/people-v-collins/) where the brilliant judge [Laurence Tribe](https://books.google.com/books?id=PFAIb6FTgY4C&lpg=PP1&dq=laurence%20tribe%20collins&pg=PT33#v=onepage&q=laurence%20tribe%20collins&f=false) schools a bunch of lawyers on proper use of statistics. Problem is that all records of the math he used are horrible. Nevertheless, I am going over his logic as a learning exercise and got to this final part and can't logic my way to how he argues this.

can you dumb this down for someone who isn't getting it?

(I get the plug and chug, it's the logic that eludes me)

*(bonus points if you can point me to a link that expands on this more recondite type of logical math like dividing probability and other stuff not covered in basic probability)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need anything more then the [definition of the conditional probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_probability)

$$
p(A \mid B) = \frac{p(A \cap B)}{p(B)}
$$

just substitute

$$
\begin{align}
p(A) &= p(c>1) \\
p(B) &= p(c\ge1) \\
p(A \cap B) &= p(c>1 \cap c\ge1) = p(c>1) = p(c\ge1) - p(c=1) \\
p(c>1\mid c\ge1) &= \frac{p(c>1)}{p(c\ge1)}
\end{align}
$$

Probability that there is more then one apple in the basket *given that* you know that there is at least one apple, is how often you observe baskets with more then one apple among the baskets with at least one apple.

Comment: thank you so much! sorry for the belated reply but it took my dumb brain a while to get it, but your explanation did it for me!

Comment: @skaai if it answered your question, consider "accepting" the answer so that others know it is "solved".

Comment: I’m new to this platform so I’m not sure if I accepted it correctly: I clicked a green check.

Comment: @skaai yes. You can check https://stats.stackexchange.com/tour for learning more.